# Can I create different retention policy for different measurements in influxdb?

Tags: influxdb

Is it possible to treat different measurements in influxdb with different a retention policy?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. What would you like to do?

Comment: I want to collect sensor data into one database from 2 kinds of sensors. Data from type 1 should expire at another age than that from sensor type 2.

Answer (score 16):

This is entirely possible with InfluxDB. To do this you'll need to create a database that has two retention policies and then write the data to the associated retention policy.

Example:

```
$ influx
> create database mydb
> create retention policy rp_1 on mydb duration 1h replication 1
> create retention policy rp_2 on mydb duration 2h replication 1
```

Now that our retention policies have been created we simple write data in the following manner:

Sensor 1 will write data to `rp_1`

```
curl http://localhost:8086/write?db=mydb&rp=rp_1 --data-binary SOMEDATA
```

Sensor 2 will write data to `rp_2`

```
curl http://localhost:8086/write?db=mydb&rp=rp_2 --data-binary SOMEDATA
```

Comment: thanks! That looks exactly like what I need. I'm gonna try this as soon as possible.

Comment: Thanks a lot:)  This is exactly what I have been looking for.