# InfluxDB - can I have different retention policy on series level within a single measurement?

Tags: influxdb

e.g.
database = 'test'
measurement = 'm1'

I want to have 1 year retention policy for points in m1 with tag='A', and 2 years retention policy for points in m1 with tag='B'

Answer (score -1):

No, retention policies apply to all records written to them. To accomplish what you want you would need to write points tagged with A to one DB/RP, and those tagged with B to a different one.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37729008/can-i-create-different-retention-policy-for-different-measurements-in-influxdb